# Show table data on screen

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a database table named zrswheel .I entered 3 datas and want to show them on screen.Here s my code

```
 REPORT  ZRS_WHEEL.

    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF ty_zrswheel,
          lv_brand TYPE c,
          lv_dimension TYPE i,
          lv_pressure TYPE i,
        END OF ty_zrswheel.
    DATA:
      wa_zrswheel TYPE ty_zrswheel,
      it_zrswheel TYPE TABLE of ty_zrswheel.

    SELECT dimension pressure brand 
        FROM zrswheel 
        INTO TABLE it_zrswheel.

    *WHERE ID=''.

    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      write: 'There is an Error in retrieving data.'.
    ELSE.
      LOOP AT it_zrswheel INTO wa_zrswheel.
        WRITE: wa_zrswheel-lv_dimension,wa_zrswheel-lv_brand,wa_zrswheel-lv_pressure.
        NEW-LINE.
      ENDLOOP.
    ENDIF.
```

When I execute I get this error:

> Runtime Errors :   DBIF_RSQL_INVALID_RSQL
>       Except.            CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB

Answer (score 1):

What is the structure of your `zrswheel`?
Does it fit to your internal structure `ty_zrswheel`?

Without knowing the structure of `zrswheel`, nobody can help you.
The following is just a guess from my side.

It is very unusual to call fields in a structure like `lv_`.
So I think your `zrswheel` is defined as:

```
dimension type c,
brand     type i
pressure  type i
```

I think your report should look like:

```
  REPORT  ZRS_WHEEL.

    DATA:
      wa_zrswheel TYPE zrswheel,
      it_zrswheel TYPE TABLE of zrswheel.

    SELECT * FROM zrswheel INTO TABLE it_zrswheel.
    LOOP AT it_zrswheel INTO wa_zrswheel.
      WRITE: / wa_zrswheel-dimension,wa_zrswheel-brand,wa_zrswheel-pressure.
    ENDLOOP.
    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      write: 'Nothing found'.
    ENDIF.
```

If you want only select an extract of zrswheel, then try:

```
  REPORT  ZRS_WHEEL.

    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF ty_zrswheel,
          brand     LIKE zrswheel-brand,     "or lv_brand?
          dimension LIKE zrswheel-dimension, "or lv_dimension?,
          pressure  LIKE zrswheel-pressure,  "or lv_pressure?,
        END OF ty_zrswheel.
    DATA:
      wa_zrswheel TYPE ty_zrswheel,
      it_zrswheel TYPE TABLE of ty_zrswheel.

    SELECT *FROM zrswheel 
        INTO corresponding fields of TABLE it_zrswheel.

    LOOP AT it_zrswheel INTO wa_zrswheel.
      WRITE: / wa_zrswheel-dimension,wa_zrswheel-brand,wa_zrswheel-pressure.
    ENDLOOP.
    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      write: 'There is an Error in retrieving data.'.
    ENDIF.
```

Remark: 
I'm not sure about the correct syntax of `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS` - please check the online help or wait for my update when I have a SAP-system to check the syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Check your order of fields in the structure and in the select statement. Ensure the data types and length match for the fields .